# Jitbit Macro Recorder - IF Pixel

Tags: if-statement, macros, pixel, recorder

how, if the desired color appears on the coordinates, does it go forward (the next command), but if the color does not appear - to go to the beginning (to the first command)?

hich command do we use for this? or better yet, the entire script? :)

Please helt, tnx ;)

I want the macro to do something for me. When I execute the commands, I get a problem when one condition is met to go forward, or if that intermediate condition is not met, to go from the beginning.

In the attached picture there is an option of what to do if the color does not appear... it is from another macro recorder

but I want to replace it or use it in jitbit recorder....[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VX1in.png)

### **example** [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUK0L.png)